# c++: how can I avoid the static_cast?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract, static-cast

I have an abstract base class and a templated derived class. Derived objects can be constructed by a previous instance of a derived object and, say, an integer. So far we have

```
struct base {
  /* ...pure virtual functions here... */

  virtual ~base() = default;
  /* NO DATA */
};

template <class D>
struct derived : base {
  derived() = default;

  derived(int x, const derived& previous) {
    /* to construct I need access to previous.data_ */
  }

  /* ...overriden virtual functions here... */

  ~derived() = default;

  D data_;
};
```

Please note that the constructor of the derived class requires access to the `data_` member of the `previous` derived object. Now I want to create a function which will construct objects of type `derived<D>` by taking as input an integer and a previous instance of `derived<D>`, and return a pointer to `base`. The problem is that since the
user will be working with `base` class pointers, the function should
look like this:

```
template <class D>
std::shared_ptr<base> getNext(int x, std::shared_ptr<base> current) {
  return std::make_shared<derived<D>>(x, *current); /* ERROR */
}
```

This, as you may have guessed, creates a compilation error saying that there is no known conversion from `base` to `derived<D>`. One thing I know I could use is a `static_cast<derived<D>&>(*current)` since the type of the underlying object will always be `derived<D>`, but ideally I would like to avoid any casts if possible.
Any ideas how to overcome this problem>? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you use copy constructor?

Comment: @John Smith: The derived constructor is not meant to simply copy the previous object. It is meant to use the data found in the previous object in order to consruct its own.

Comment: @HeywoodFloyd: I do not think it would matter. The problem is created by the input parameter of getNext and not its return type.

Comment: If you know the object passed in will always be derived, why not pass in a pointer to derived as a parameter?

Comment: @HeywoodFloyd: It will give the same error. Keep in mind that the user will only have in his program pointers to base, therefore he/she will pass a base pointer as argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're working with a polymorphic class and find yourself needing to cast to the derived type, this is often a clue that something is wrong with the design.  After all, why have `virtual` functions if you still need to get to the derived class?  I'm not saying there are no exceptions to this -- but I will say they are few and far between.

In this case, you (think you) need to cast in order to clone the object.  Instead, I'd provide a `clone` method on the base class (here called `getNext`).  Make that `virtual`, override it in the derived class, and call that instead:

```
struct base {
public:
  virtual std::shared_ptr<base> getNext(int x) = 0;
};

template <typename D>
struct derived : public base
{
public:
  std::shared_ptr<base> getNext(int x)
  { 
    std::shared_ptr <derived> clone = std::make_shared <derived<d>> (x, *this);
    return std::static_pointer_cast <base> (clone);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtual accessor-functions in the base class which tells which type the derived classes are. Then you can use `static cast` safely to cast the base class.

```
class Animal {
    virtual bool isDog() { return false; }
    virtual bool isCat() { return false; }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
    virtual bool isDog() { return true; }
};

class Cat : public Animal {
    virtual bool isCat() { return true; }
};
```

I can then cast the base class safely like this:

```
Dog A;
Cat B;

Animal *unknown_animal = &A;

if (unknown_animal->isDog()) {
    Dog *dog = static_cast<Dog*>(unknown_animal);
}
else if (unknown_animal->isCat()) {
    Cat *cat = static_cast<Cat*>(unknown_animal);
}
```

The accessor functions are also useful if you only need to *know* the derived type, but don't need to *access it*.

Answer (score 0):

You would not want to use `static_cast` for this anyway; you'd want to use [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/) (and check the result to make sure it was castable to your derived type).

If your interface has all the information you need to fill in your `Data` object, you can create a conversion constructor that will allow you to avoid doing the cast:

```
template<typename T>
class MyDerived : public Base
{
public:
    // other functions
    MyDerived(std::shared_ptr<Base> p)
    {
        // initialize _data
    }

private:
    Data _data;
};
```